# Sharing image on Whatsapp : Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, whatsapp

Hi I am trying to create a simple android code of sharing QR code image via Whatsapp.But even though QR code is being properly generated and image is being also stored in the emulator, the image share to Whatsapp(via Intent) doesnt happen and the application crashes in phone but works in emulator.Here below is my code snippet.

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    // you can set menu header with title icon etc
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Share It");
    // add menu items
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share on Whatsapp");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share on Email");


}
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Share on Whatsapp")
    {
         Uri imageUri=getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imageUri.getPath().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //  Log.e("Check",imageUri.getPath().toString());
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title + "\n\nLink : " + link );
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageUri.getPath()));
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via:"));
        //Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
       /* Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //Target whatsapp:
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        //Add text and then Image URI
       // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, picture_text);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);*/

        try {
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception "+ex.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage().toString());
            //Toast.makeText("Whatsapp not installed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText("Whatsapp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else if (item.getTitle() == "Share on Email")
    {
        ;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Here is the crash report on phone

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:490)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:480)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:452)
    at com.sudarshan.qrcodegenerator.MainActivity.getImageUri(MainActivity.java:109)
    at com.sudarshan.qrcodegenerator.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:117)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3628)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$PhoneWindowMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3750)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:776)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:923)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:913)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1165)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3145)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4077)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3831)
    at android.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:116)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12558)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3079)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2407)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12804)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5428)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5219)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4730)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4889)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4946)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4730)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4730)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7533)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7502)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7459)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7657)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:246)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

Comment: can you please share your log cat with us so we can trace the error?

Comment: `shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");` Try to do without.

Comment: `String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insert........` Please tell which path you get.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
` You could as well remove those lines as the result is unused.

Comment: I have changed the code now a little but the code works fine in emulator but crashes on phone.